# My OGL program cannot find gl.h and glu.h anymore

Tags: c, opengl, codeblocks, glfw, glew

I have an Ogl program that I used to compile just fine. However, after a couple months without working on it, I came back, send my IDE codeblocks to compile it, and ir returned:

> /.../glew-2.1.0/include/GL/glew.h|1205|error: GL/glu.h: No such file or directory|
>
> /.../glfw-2.7.9/include/GL/glfw.h|176|error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory|

So it opens the glew header and points to these lines:

```
  #include <GL/gl.h>
  #include <GL/glu.h>
```

Some observations. 1) It worked just fine last time. 2) I do not use Glu.

I believe some configuration was inadvertently changed. The question is: Where?

My first hypothesis is the IDE. I looked in it and everything seems about right. In the tab "The Linker Settings" of the Project Build Options the .so library files of glfw and glew are there. In the "Search Directories" tab there is link to glew/include/GL and /glfw/include/GL

In the first of these directories is the glfw header. On the latter, glew.h and three other glew related header files.

Looking for the for glu.h and the gl.h header files on the entire system, I could not find anything. I did an

> sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev

but it did not change anything when I try to compile the program.

Is there other codeblocks settings that needs to be adjusted and I am missing? On the system misconfiguration, where else I can look for useful information? Which cause seems more likely?

Comment: Why such an ancient GLFW?

Comment: use file manager and go to  `/.../glfw-2.7.9/include/GL/` location to check if your GL headers are present at the desired location...  If your setup had updated something the version number along the path could changed (either in IDE/compiler or on HDD) another option (if the files are where there should be) could be change in access privileges or anti-virus intervention. What OS? You can download the missing GL headers from nVidia. It also might be a problem with relative paths include ... in such case try use `#include <gl.h>`

Comment: Do a forced reinstallation of mesa-common-dev, i.e. `sudo apt-get install -f mesa-common-dev` – if the package was already installed, then a normal `apt-get install` turns into a no-op.

Comment: @datenwolf. Tried it and the complaint about the gl.h was gone. However, the one about glu remained. And the most awkward thing about it, is that I DO NOT use glu. Nonetheless, it keep complaining about it and mentions my function "display", that I read every line and there is no call to glu. There is one call to "glfwSwapBuffers" that perhaps uses glu?

Comment: @Spektre. I changed the glfw header to #include <glu.h>. It did not work, as expected, since I could not find the glu header in my system. The gl.h is working after following datenwolf suggestion. Will try to figure out the correct package that contains it or look for it in isolation in some website.

Comment: @genpfault New glfw requires new cmake. New cmake requires new gcc. New gcc unfortunatelly requires more free space than I have available on my system.

Comment: Success! sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev did the work and putted glu.h in a GL folder on a system
dir. It keep being awkward that I needed glu when I am not suing it! (at least not directly)

Answer (score 6):

Search your package manager for mesa and glu

`sudo apt-cache search mesa | grep glu`

You should see a package in there that will have the glu headers in there. For me, I fixed this issue with

`sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev`

Similar to this post:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mesa-glut-libraries-178145/